# Is it possible to make a mbr legacy bootcamp win 10 from a gpt partitioned hdd on catalina 10.15.7 with bootcamp 6?

Tags: windows-10, boot-camp, mbr, gpt, efi

I tried to install win10 to ssd via efi boot on my macbook air 2012, it ran pretty well as far as performance, but because it's pre-uefi it makes it the garbage windows version with no sound, no proper graphics card, can't change brightness, it's awful, then I tried parallels, and I can tell already that it's going to suck how the mouse moves so that's out.

So, my only option is to try a legacy bootcamp partition install somehow sharing the same hdd as my macOS (which has plenty of room and is fast), but this is mostly a novelty thing, I have a windows laptop, so if there's a risk of mangling my mac I'll just get a newer macbook eventually, but if it's doable safely, any resources would be appreciated as I looked online and it's a mess of forum posts of peoples' problems.

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/402563/is-it-possible-to-make-a-mbr-legacy-bootcamp-win-10-from-a-gpt-partitioned-catal

Comment: sorry, wasn't sure which got more traffic/was more appropriate for this question.

Comment: This gets more traffic, Ask Different is more specialist. I'd suggest AD would be better for this, but it's on-topic for both, which is why sometimes you have to flip a coin ;)

Comment: doubt I'll get a response in either for this obscure question but it has been my observation super user is more busy, good to have confirmed, and handles mac questions too so it's a bit confusing, I'll use super user from now on for mac questions.